# Passing Date Object With Ajaxpro

Tags: javascript, parsing, ajaxpro

I pass an javascript object from client-side to server-side function with Ajaxpro. 
In server-side date variables comes inside object are looks like below. What does it mean? How can i parse it to formatted date?

"/Date(1280381400000)/"

Answer (score 0):

The number could be number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 midnight. You need to construct the date object by passing this milliseconds and then format it.